# Length of the sum of two integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm programming an integer class and I seem to have encountered a performance bottleneck when attempting to obtain the length of a given integer. I currently do so by finding a leading zero and using that index as a reference point to begin counting. I want to find a faster way to do this, and I believe the following question will help me:

Given two integers, is there a way to determine the length of their sum? Can we express it as a function of the two integers?

To clarify, the length of a number is simply the number of digits it has.

Note: I don't know which area of mathematics this would fall under, so my choice of the number theory tag may be incorrect.

Comment: If you mean the expansion in any base (eg $10$ or $2$), the length of a sum of two integers is at most one plus the bigger of the lengths of the terms, and at least the bigger of the lengths of the terms. It is the former iff you have to “carry the one” (or however it’s actually said in English) when doing the addition.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I hadn't thought to use this property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\log_{10} 1,000,000 = 6\phantom{000}$$
$$\log_{10} \phantom{0}900,000 \approx 5.95$$

So, in base $10$, if the sum of $a$ and $b$ is positive, the length of $a+b = 1+ \lfloor \log_{10} (a+b) \rfloor$.

An algorithm might be:

If $a+b=0$, then $L(a+b) = 1,$
else $L(a+b) = 1+ \lfloor \log_{10} |a+b| \rfloor$.  This is assuming the length does not include the (possible) minus sign.